# Ubuntu 12.04 System crashes right after login - Boot-Repair log included

Tags: 12.04, hardware, boot-repair

Wow, my system crashes hard - right after login!  I've heard about quite some crashed with Ubuntu 12.04. ... any suggestions on how to proceed?

Here is the **link to the logfile** of Boot-Repair - which I tried without success *(details see below)*:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1630291/

Also, running memtest86 from the boot-up program resulted in 0 errors found.  Neither, did a check on the harddrives yield an error message.

**Further Details**

Ubuntu will boot fine up to the login screen.  Then - after I enter the password and hit login - it will hang.  I am not able to enter anything at the **resulting screen** *(see image - larger view [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nM1W2.jpg))*.

[image: Screen after crashing]

The first time this occurred was right after I cleaned my computer carefully with aerosol. **Maybe a hardware damage**? But I don't think so, it was minimal maintenance mostly focusing on the cooling-fans. Also, I removed an old harddisk (no boot partition, just mp3 data).

**Regarding Boot-Repair** ... ran it through UbuntuSecureRemix (a Ubuntu boot mix CD) a and used the standard option "Recommendend repair - repairs most frequent problems".

Comment: You can reach the login screen, so the problem is located after the bootloader (GRUB). SO Boot-Repair can't help. I would bet you have a memory (RAM) problem. Try checking it.

Comment: Ran memtest86 from the boot-up program and it reported 0 errors after 2 passes.  From what I've read none of the memory modules should be faulty/replaced in this case?  Any further suggestions?

Comment: Just got through checking the harddrives ... no errors reported either.  Rebooted the system to the same ... crash! :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got back into my system and it is running.

To help others, here is the simple fix:

**All I had to do is boot into an older kernel! :)** (here is an explanation on how to do it https://askubuntu.com/questions/97731...keeps-crashing )

Note though, that I had to go back to a kernel as low as 2.6.x. I won't reinstall for now - there are too many issues reported with 12.04. or 12.10. - but if I notice unusual behavior I will. Now, is a good time to run another backup on /home.

Comment: glad you found a workaround. I strongly recommend you create a bug report (via the `ubuntu-bug linux` command), so that developers can fix the bug in next Ubuntu releases.

Comment: this is fun ... `ubuntu-bug linux` responded with "Problem in linux-image-2.6.32-45-generic ... The problem cannot be reported: This is not an official Ubuntu package. Please remove any third party package and try again."

Comment: ok. Then report the bug directly here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+filebug